# disable click event on complete document except one single div

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

i have a web page in my MVC application. like this

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="1st_section"> Contents................... so on</div>
<div id="2th_section">Contents................... so on</div>
<div id="3th_section">Contents................... so on</div>
<div id="4th_section">Contents................... so on</div>
</body>
</html>
```

while rendering this page in Browser, we need to do mouse click enable to 
`<div id="1st_section"> Contents................... so on</div>` this section only. Except this section the mouse click  event should be disabled in entire web page.

Can you please suggest possible way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have click handlers from elsewhere, you could [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) using the `*` - universal selector:

```
$(function(){
    $('*').unbind('click');
    $('body > div#1st_section').bind('click', function(){
      //bind event listener goes here
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

using jquery [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) and [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div[id$='_section']").click(function(){
        alert('clicked');
    });
});
```

`$("div[id$='_section']")` selects all divs with value ending exactly with a `_section`.

**Update**

after updated question..if you need for only one then use id selector

```
$(function(){
$("#1st_section").click(function() {
   alert('clicked');
})
});
```

Comment: Does this cover the scenario that the OP wanted, disabling click on the rest of the page?

Comment: since the click event for document is not mentioned... even though clicking on document there will be no changes unless you have something like `$(document).click(function(){...})` in your document... with this could he 'll get an alert only when the specified id is clicked..

Answer (score 2):

You can attach handler to whole body but perform action when clicked on desired element.

```
var handler = function(event){    
    if($(event.target).is("#1st_section"))
              // do something
    else
         return false;
}
$(document).on("click", handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since id is unique, why not:

```
$("#1st_section").click(function() {
    // Your code here for 1st_section, the other sections and elements will not be affected
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you CAN DO THIS.

Using "pointer-events:none" along with CSS conditional statements for IE, you can get a cross browser compatible solution for this problem.

using AlphaImageLoader you can even put transparent PNG/GIFs in the overlay div and have clicks flow through to elements underneath.

```
     pointer-events:none;
     background:url('your_transparent.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.off() and .on()` handlers for binding the events and an universal selector `*` to disable the click:

Try this:

```
$('*').off('click'); //<-----take out the click from every item on the page

$('#1st_section').on('click', function () { //<-binding the click to specific div
   alert('clicked');
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UV33n/)

Answer (score -1):

you want click only on this and its have Id as well

```
<div id="1st_section"> Contents................... so on</div>
```

so you can select this by using # selector for Ids . and you can use following code in jquery to generate click event

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#1st_section").click(function(){
//       here you code which you want to execute on click event 
    });
});
```

and in case you want to remove event handler you can use  off() of jquery

[Remove an event handler.](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

**EDITED :**

so you can try something like this to remove all click events from document and add click event on that div

```
$(function () {
    $('*').off('click');
    $('#1st_section').on('click', function () {
        alert('HI');
    });
});
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK FOR THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/NfN5Z/2/)